# Nvidia driver installed but not running

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-geforce

I have ubuntu 18.04 with nvidia geforce 1050Ti
I have installed nvidia driver (390 first and than 430)
from the installation it looks like everything went well
When I run nvidia-setting it states I am running GPU
also when I run nvidia-prime query it return nvidia
But when I do nvidia-smi, I get an output which says

No running processes found

Also if I look at the "about" I see that it runs the intel card.

Any ideas ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you rebooted the host since installing?

Comment: yes I have rebooted many times

Comment: Maybe try running `sudo prime-select intel` then reboot.  Then run `sudo prime-select nvidia` and then reboot again and see if it selects the proper driver now.  I have been looking around and some people have claimed that selecting the other, rebooting, then selecting the one you want has made it so the system selected the right card.

Comment: Tried selecting intel rebooting and than selecting nvidia. No help there.